# How to dispose root in amchart5 for multiple graph using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to dispose root in amchart5 for multiple but it give me error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dom')

making graph when i loaded graph more than 2 times or when i click a particular tab then loaded a graph then want to distroyed prevous root and create a new root in amchart5